# changing multiple video src via onClick

Tags: javascript, html

how do i change multiple video src via onClick? i currently have a video tag

```
<video id="videofilmtv" width="480" height="270">
    <source src="movies/vid1.ogv" id="ogg1" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="movies/vid1.webm" id="webm1" type="video/webm">
    <source src="movies/vid1.mp4" id="mp41" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
```

a link

```
<a href="#" onClick="changevid(A);">
```

and the javascript

```
var A = 'movies/vid2.ogv';
var B = 'movies/vid2.webm';
var C = 'movies/vid2.mp4';

function changevid(q) {
    if (changevid(A)) {
        document.getElementById('ogg1').setAttribute('src', A);
        document.getElementById('webm1').setAttribute('src', B);
        document.getElementById('mp41').setAttribute('src', C);
    }
}
```

it doesn't seem to work. any ideas why? or is there another way? thanks

Comment: arent you forgetting to append the `"movies/"` to the `src` first?

Comment: thanks, i did add it back in but it's still the same..

Comment: i dont quite understand the logic of your `changevid` function, can you explain in words what this `if()` condition of yours supposed to check ?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to check which link it's coming from so if it's from changevid(A) then do the following

Comment: In that case have a look at my answer, your condition statement needs to be altered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how `if()` statement works:

you need to change your condition and the way you call the function for it to work.

try this:

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" onClick="changevid('A');">
```

**JS**

```
var A = 'movies/vid2.ogv';
var B = 'movies/vid2.webm';
var C = 'movies/vid2.mp4';

function changevid(q) {
    if (q=='A') {
        //get the video element:
        var _VideoElement = document.getElementById('videofilmtv');
        //find out which of the currently playing sources is playing:
        var _CurrentlyPlayingFile = _VideoElement.currentSrc
        //check the filetype of the playing source:
        var _SourceFileType = _CurrentlyPlayingFile.substr(_CurrentlyPlayingFile.length-3, _CurrentlyPlayingFile.length)
        //check extension and apply new video accordingly
        if(_SourceFileType=="mp4"){
            //you cannot access the <source> children of the video, to change the 
            //video source you need to access the Video Element source directly.
            _VideoElement.setAttribute('src', C);
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/7r3ebhLt/)**</kbd>

Comment: Just tried this, doesn't seem to work though.. the initial video is still the video even after i clicked on the link

Comment: this is because you are unable to access the `<source>` children. you need to change the source of the video element itself. i have updated the answer with an example

Comment: Thanks! it's working so far. I just have to test it on a few more browsers :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling "changevid( )" function inside "changevid( )" function. This leads the function is called infinite times which causes to exceed maximum stack size..

Answer (score 0):

That `<source>` element doesn't work like that, i don't believe.  `<source>` elements allow the browser to select what resource to load into the video.src attribute (i.e., what video-format) when it loads the video tag into the page.  I don't think that changing the source.src attribute does anything once the video has initially loaded.  Anyway, I've never seen that done, but it's been a while since I did a lot with video.

To do what you are trying to do you need to use video.canPlayType api to determine the correct video format for this device/browser then do `video.setAttribute('src', 'video2.X');`  Where `X` is one of the formats that is playable by this device/browser.

Comment: I believe (100%) that changing the `src` attribute loads a new media source to that element >> just like iframe does, image etc.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, the W3C spec disagrees with you:

"Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the element is already inserted in a video or audio element will have no effect. To change what is playing, just use the src attribute on the media element directly, possibly making use of the canPlayType() method to pick from amongst available resources. Generally, manipulating source elements manually after the document has been parsed is an unnecessarily complicated approach"

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-source-element

Comment: I just *agree* that [The specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#dom-navigator-canplaytype) are there to read (carefully) and for us to [test](http://jsfiddle.net/xcpg51ye/) (Hope I'm not missing anything ;) )

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, yes your demo illustrates the correct way to do it, you must change the `<video>` `src` attribute to swap videos.  However my comment is about the incorrectness of trying to swap video source media by changing the `<source>` `src` attribute which is what the OP is currently doing and which according to HTML5 spec is a non-op.

Comment: Wupp! So basically we were talking about the same things :D it's possible using video's `src` but not `<source>`'s src

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
var link1 = ['movies/vid1.ogv', 'movies/vid1.webm', 'movies/vid1.mp4'];
var link2 = ['movies/vid2.ogv', 'movies/vid2.webm', 'movies/vid2.mp4'];

function changevid(q) {
    if (q==='A') {
        document.getElementById('ogg1').setAttribute('src', link1[0]);
        document.getElementById('webm1').setAttribute('src', link1[1]);
        document.getElementById('mp41').setAttribute('src', link1[2]);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('ogg1').setAttribute('src', link2[0]);
        document.getElementById('webm1').setAttribute('src', link2[1]);
        document.getElementById('mp41').setAttribute('src', link2[2]);
    }
}

<a href="#" onClick="changevid('A');">
```

Your current `IF` statement doesn't make sense in it's current form. This will allow you to toggle between the links

Comment: I tried your solution as well and nothing happened when i clicked the link. the initial video was still on the screen, paused. (not restarted)